Huffman coding rules and optimization
All sources i've read quote the below process to get Huffman codes:

Arrange the elements in ascending order of their frequencies.
Create a binary tree by repeatedly combining the two least frequent elements into a single node, with the sum of their frequencies as the frequency of the new node.
Assign '0' to the left branch and '1' to the right branch at each step.
The Huffman code for each element is obtained by traversing from the root of the tree to the respective leaf node, recording the path taken (0 for left, 1 for right).

Let's try this for the following Frequency Map:
A -> 1 B -> 2 C -> 3 D -> 4
Making the Tree
        (ABCD, 10)
       /          \
   (ABC, 6)         D:4
   /     \
 (AB, 3)  C:3
 /    \
A:1   B:2

Following this tree to get the codes:
A -> 000 B -> 001 C -> 01 D -> 1
Obviously, the Max depth and the max code length does not follow the logical rule of being log2(nElement), which in this case should be two.
Optimally the codes would be:
A -> 00 B -> 01 C -> 10 D -> 11
So what's goin on here ? what am i doing wrong ?

"Obviously, the Max depth and the max code length does not follow the logical rule of being log2(nElement), which in this case should be two." why should it? That way the most common symbol - D - uses two bits instead of one. Huffman code does not optimize max code length/depth, it optimizes the length of a sufficiently long text where symbols occur with given frequencies. Also, it provides an optimal solution, not "THE" optimal solution, it's possible yours would be just as good.

Aand I confirmed it - for String "ABBCCCDDDD" (each letter with proper frequency) huffman gives 19 characters, your encoding gives 20.

Imagine encoding String "ABBCCCDDDD" - sample string where each symbol occurs with the given frequency.
Huffman encoding you came up with encodes it as 0000010010101011111 - 19 characters.
Your encoding where you optimized for max code length gives 00010110101011111111 - 20 characters.
Your mistake is thinking that max depth is what's being optimized (or what needs to be optimized) - but Huffman encoding optimizes for encoded text length.
And as a side note, as I mentioned in a comment, Huffman produces "an" optimal solution, not "the" optimal solution, it's possible I think for a lower-depth solution to be just as good, but it won't be better.

Your "logical rule" would be logical only if the symbols had equal probability. In that case the Huffman code would be as flat as possible. If the number of symbols is a power of two, 2n, then each equiprobable symbol would take n bits in the Huffman code.
However, the whole point of Huffman coding is to take fewer total bits to code the symbols when the probabilties are not equal, and especially when the probabilties are signifcantly skewed. Then the number of bits for a symbol will be approximately –lg(p), where lg is the logarithm base 2, and p is the probability of the symbol. Going back to the equiprobable case with 2n symbols, each symbol has probability 2-n, so –log(p) is n, as expected. However for your four symbols, the expected number of bits per code would be about A 3.3, B 2.3, C 1.7, D 1.3. The closest you can get to that for codes that have an integral number of bits and that are decodable is 3, 3, 2, 1. (If B were two bits, B, C, and D would use up all of the prefix codes, leaving none for A.)
